# Python Django flow and navigation

Tags: python, django

This is the current project stucture

```
R6Scorextractor


        R6Scoreex
                 migrations
                 templates
                          R6Scoreex
                                   header.html
                                   home.html


                 __Init__.py
                 settings.py
                 urls.py 
                 views.py
                 models.py
                 apps.py
                 admin.py
                 tests.py
        R6Scorextractor
                 __Init__.py
                 settings.py
                 urls.py 
        manage.py
```

*R6Scorextractor/R6scoreex/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),




]
```

*R6Scorextractor/R6scoreex/views.py*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pdb;

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'R6scoreex/home.html')


def simple_upload(request):


    print "Entered simple_upload"

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'R6scoreex/home.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    return render(request, 'R6scoreex/home.html')
```

*R6Scorextractor/R6Scorextractor/url.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('R6scoreex.urls')),
]
```

I just want to know how to call simple_upload inside views.py of  R6scoreex module.How to write URL for it , server gives me 404 error when I went with the following

```
url(r'^/simple_upload/$', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),
```

[image]

So what is the reason I am getting 404 error even after adding the above code what am I doing wrong here

### [Click this link to download the copy of the site](https://files.fm/u/eaamjuu3)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is wrong with the current code? What happens?

Comment: @DanielRoseman currently am trying to call def simple_upload( but it always goes to the index function in views.Please don't upvote without reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On urls.py in R6Scorextractor you are using

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'R6scoreex/', include('R6scoreex.urls')),
]
```

this means you are mapping all the R6scoreex.urls to a path starting with "R6scoreex/"

That's why you can access from localhost:8000/R6scoreex/simple_upload/

if you change to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('R6scoreex.urls')),
]
```

you should be able to access from
localhost:8000/simple_upload/

i hope i made it clear, if not feel free to ask anything

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/R6Scoreex/simple_upload/ guys this gives 404  I have no clue why this is happening

Comment: http://localhost:8000/R6scoreex/simple_upload/ works here without modification, could you provide the error it shows?on console

Comment: ooo ye, ITS R6s not R6S, its case sensitive, click on my link above

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very strange. I took the time to download and setup your django project to check what could be wrong. These are the steps I took:

- Unrar the file to a new folder.
- Install virtual enviroment. (I found out you are using python2).

  ```
  virtualenv -p path/to/python2 env
  source env/bin/activate
  pip install django
  ```

The ONLY change that I made to your project was from ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] in settings.py.

Then I ran it:

```
cd R6Scorextractor
python manage.py runserver
```

And it worked:

- I went to the root url and 404: that's correct.
- Then to /R6scoreex/ and:
  [image]
- Next to /R6scoreex/simple_upload
  [image]
  [image]

I was thinking that it's very unlikelly that your problem is ALLOWED_HOSTS. And after doing all this I figure out that you are using the wrong url...

You are not supposed to go to `127.0.0:8000/simple_upload/`. Your setup is pointing to `127.0.0:8000/R6scoreex/simple_upload/`

If you want `127.0.0:8000/simple_upload/` you should change `url(r'R6scoreex/', include('R6scoreex.urls'))` to `url(r'/', include('R6scoreex.urls'))`

Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/R6Scoreex/simple_upload/ guys this gives 404 this is the reason I put up the post

Comment: I had switched between both the cases you guys have mentioned in your answer and tico thanks for the effort .I have tried  
127.0.0.1:8000/R6Scoreex/simple_upload as well as  
127.0.0.1:8000/simple_upload with the right url mapping but I failed understand why the error was happening thats why I posted the question.

Comment: @SachinDivakar Humm.. I said that was the wrong url because of the screenshot. Ok. I cannot reproduce your error. It works out of the box for me. So I'm left with only one option: there is something else in your enviroment that is messing up with django. I strongly advise you to install a virtual enviroment, activate it, install django again inside the enviroment and check if it works.

Comment: I have given you bounty because its the right answer and you were the first to actually come to help but giving a 15 to zero because he is knew to community and his answer is also right

Comment: Can you help me with a little thing .See I have some files in the media folder which I uploaded but when I type the link or add it as src to img tag it never gets displayed.how should I add another url map for diplaying images

Comment: Short answer is use static not media in development. With default configuration, you should create a static folder inside your app and put your images there. you can access them by typing domain/static/my_app/example.jpg. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: tico so with respect to current directory structure domainname/static/ instead of my_app is it R6Scoreex ??? or do I have to write R6Scorextractor ?

Comment: It's R6Scoreex. R6Scorextractor is the only folder in that structure which is not an app. It's more like a project settings and a place to put cross-app code.

Answer (score -1):

The include in R6Scorextractor/urls.py should be empty.

```
url('', include('R6scoreex.urls')),
```

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in R6Scorextractor.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$ [name='simple_upload']
The current path, simple_upload, didn't match any of these.
. This was the response that I got  what am I doing wrong here .